# Google gaming services, obtain list of rooms

Tags: android

I am planning on introducing Google play game services to my app. However I am not sure if i can provide the following capability. I need to be able to list the rooms available so the player can join any room he chooses rather than auto join.

Is there a way to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current implementation of our API, there are no "open rooms" that you can voluntarily enter. You need an invitation to enter a room. So the method we have that's closest to what you're asking is the [GamesClient.loadInvitations()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadInvitations%28com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationsLoadedListener%29) method, which will list all the currently active invitations to rooms that the player has.

If the behavior you're trying to implement is "I want to join a room that's playing upside-down four-dimensional chess", without being specifically invited by a friend, then what you want is probably *automatching*. Automatching means you create a room and specify the number of players you want in your game and, optionally, a variant code (an integer) that indicates the game type. Then, the API will match together a set of players who is wanting to play that same variant at that moment, and will put them all in the same room.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's perfect answer. It just needs more improvement and it will be perfect. What I am worried about is invitation to be sent to one person and this person is sleeping. Then you have 3 people waiting for him and game can't be started. If it was room concepts like most games, then you can see the activeness of people

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [Leaderboards in Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards)

Comment: This is to compare people scores of each other. I am talking about displaying game rooms so player can join any

Comment: @Snake i have spent some time on Google play game services , i am not sure google provide that , it seems you have to create your own web services to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you could do this in the current release of Game Services (at least not if you use the API in the way that Google wants you to).

However I just noticed this:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/rooms/join

> Join a room. For internal use by the Games SDK only. Calling this
>   method directly is unsupported.

Maybe this sort of thing will be possible at a later date ?

Comment: Ok that hit the nail on the head, we know now it is not supported