# Turn based android game with Google Play Game Services and IntentService

Tags: android, google-play-games

Imagine a multi player game for android which is turn based (multiplayer like ruzzle):
The user should get invitation, accept, send finished game to other players, etc at any time, even if the game/activity is not open. Each game last more than a day.

At the I/O google mentioned that Google Play Game Services will support "turn based multiplayer" gaming experience as well. What do they mean by this?

When I was reading about it on [developers website](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer), I did not see "turn based" anywhere. Also the title of the page was:

> Developing a **Real-time** Multiplayer Game in Android

Can what I need be accomplished using google play game services and an `IntentService`? What would the drawback of this be compared to using `GoogleCloudMessaging`?

Can I hook up `onActivityResult` to an `IntentService` so invitation, game messages, etc will be handled by the `IntentService` if the game/activity is not running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I read [Google Play Services 4.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2014/01/google-play-services-41.html) and it looks promising. I wanted to share this with whoever stumbles upon this question.

> **Turn Based Multiplayer**
>
> Play Games now supports turn-based multiplayer!
> Developers can build asynchronous games to play with friends and
> auto-matched players, supporting 2-8 players per game. When players
> take turns, their turn data is uploaded to Play Services and shared
> with other players automatically.

[TurnbasedMultiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer)

Comment: it's not well explained. i got confused while looking at: official website. Is there any good tutorial type thing? because on official site they tell us every concept and I got confuse, which is not good for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you are thinking about developing an asynchronous game. This has been previously discussed here e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423461/example-of-google-play-service-for-creating-a-turn-by-turn-asynchronous-multip

Google Play Game Services is not well-suited to this type of game at the moment.

Of course, you can write your own intent service, but to make it work (e.g. maintaining "connections" between devices across power downs) you will effectively have to write your own version of Game Services.

Re. reconnecting to a room (assuming Google's back end has not "housekept" the room due to inactivity):

[Google gaming services, obtain list of rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637799/google-gaming-services-obtain-list-of-rooms/17682026#17682026)

Comment: I read the page you gave the link to... It's kinda old and also the answers are incomplete and not referenced. How about "Can I hook up onActivityResult to an IntentService so invitation, game messages, etc will be handled by the IntentService if the game/activity is not runnin?"

Comment: "Kinda old" ? 17 days ago ? I suggest you edit your question title then, but it doesn't fundamentally change the answer to your question.

Comment: But if I user game services for the invitation to a game and accepting invitations, it would handle emailing the invited user to install my game, right? There are other benefits to it as well, like eventually getting a badge on the play store. The question is would it be possible? Can I reconnect to a room later on? Are there any other implications? (Question edited)

Comment: I agree that if I was trying to do what you are trying to do I would use as much of Game Services as possible. Re. your specific question about reconnecting to a room - I think the answer (at the moment) is no. I'm going to update my answer with a reference to that in a few mins...

Comment: Thanks for your help :) (up vote). I'll keep the question open to see if there is anyone who knows a workaround or when it becomes possible.

Comment: You are welcome - btw I know you weren't satisfied with the first "answer" I referenced and I understand your reasons for that. The way I look at this is that these questions and answers are looked at by many people (80+ in the case of that one). Some of these people probably have inside knowledge and would set the record straight (some Google people have been actively contributing answers to Game Services  questions on this forum in recent weeks).